# Thumbnails in Google search results for mobile are cropped

Tags: google-search, googlebot-mobile, thumbnail

I have a problem with the thumbnail images shown on google search results page.

If I search for "Kevin Sneader" on mobile (iOS or Android), the images seem to be cropped in the thumbnail in Google search results, but if I search for "Liz Hilton Segel", these images seem to be fine. Both are on the same page (i.e. use the same HTML), so why is that the first image is being cropped. Screenshots below:

**Cropped image screenshot:**

[image]

** Another image screenshot, which is coming okay:**

[image]

I have gone through some related links, but am totally not getting as to what could be causing this.

One input is that both might have different aspect ratios, which could be causing this, but not sure.

Comment: Is this powered by some Schema.org markup?  If so, can you share it.  Can you share links to the two images from your site?  That would make it easier to compare aspect ratios.

Comment: Hey @StephenOstermiller, there is an attribute as itemtype="https://schema.org/Person" added to the picture element in the markup.
And the links to images are - https://www.mckinsey.com/~/media/McKinsey/Our%20People/Kevin%20Sneader/VI-Kevin-Sneader_8756_blue-tone_1008H.ashx?mw=726 and https://www.mckinsey.com/~/media/McKinsey/Our%20People/Liz%20Hilton%20Segel/New%20blue/Liz_Hilton_Segel_016293_blue-tone_simp_1008H.ashx?mw=726.
Also, in both cases, for mobile view, there is same image loaded, but its cropped in aspect ratio of 1:1.